# Add frequency (number of occurrences) to my table of text through awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Given this input table:

```
pac1 xxx 
pac1 yyy
pac1 zzz
pac2 xxx
pac2 uuu
pac3 zzz
pac3 uuu
pac4 zzz
```

I need to add frequencies to third column like this:

```
pac1 xxx 2/3
pac1 yyy 1/3
pac1 zzz 3/3
pac2 xxx 2/2
pac2 uuu 2/2
pac3 zzz 2/2
pac3 uuu 2/2
pac4 zzz 3/1
```

Where first number is number of occurrences in second column.

```
awk '{print $2}' input | sort | uniq -c
```

And number after slash is uniq occurrences of first column:

```
awk '{print $1}' input | sort | uniq -c
```

I would like to use implementation in awk.

EDIT:

Please modify the output - first column are names and I need to count how many uniq names is occur in first column like:

```
pac1 xxx 2/4
pac1 yyy 1/4
pac1 zzz 3/4
pac2 xxx 2/4
pac2 uuu 2/4
pac3 zzz 2/4
pac3 uuu 2/4
pac4 zzz 3/4
```

So uniq names are only pac1,pac2,pac3,pac4 => 4

Something like this:

```
occur=$(awk '{print $1}' input | sort | wc -l)

awk -v occur=$occur '{col2[$2]++} {print $0, col2[$2] "/" occur}' file
```

A would like to avoid variable $occur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just read the file twice: first to count the values and store them in an array, then to print its values:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {col1[$1]++; col2[$2]++; next} {print $0, col2[$2] "/" col1[$1]}' file file
pac1 xxx 2/3
pac1 yyy 1/3
pac1 zzz 3/3
pac2 xxx 2/2
pac2 uuu 2/2
pac3 zzz 3/2
pac3 uuu 2/2
pac4 zzz 3/1
```

The `FNR==NR {things; next}` is a trick to do things just when reading the first file. It is based on using `FNR` and `NR`: the former means Field Number of Record and the latter Number of Record. This means that FNR contains the number of line of the current file, while NR contains the number of lines that have been read so far overall, making `FNR==NR` true just when reading the first file. By adding `next` we skip the current line and jump to the next one.

Find more info in [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

---

Regarding your update: if you want the last item to contain the count of different values in the first column, just check the length of the array that was created. This will tell you many different indexes it contains, and hence the value you want:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {col1[$1]++; col2[$2]++; next} {print $0, col2[$2] "/" length(col1)}' file file
pac1 xxx 2/4
pac1 yyy 1/4
pac1 zzz 3/4
pac2 xxx 2/4
pac2 uuu 2/4
pac3 zzz 3/4
pac3 uuu 2/4
pac4 zzz 3/4
```

Comment: thank you nice solution. So it is mean, that after `next` awk reading a processing second file?

Comment: @Geroge it is a trick to read just the first file. Check my update with more info.

Comment: thank you so much it is work very well. Would you mind to add update for awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c - this would be second number. Probably I can skip sorting, because first column is sorted.

Comment: @Geroge as Ed Morton pointed out, the Edit 2 does not make much sense. Try to specify the algorithm with which this should work, because to me it is very unclear.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I concatanate my file and pipe it to your awk solution? Something like cat *txt | 'your_awk_solution' - -  ??

Comment: @Geroge just say `awk '...' *txt`

Comment: There is a probem when I use script in for loop - for i in *txt do awk '...' $i $i doesnot work.. I found some roundabout, but did you faced this "issue"? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `awk`, then you will want to run through every line, and collect some information using three associative arrays.  One to collect the raw data, one to count the instances of column 2 duplication, and one to count the instances of column 3 duplication. Then, have an `END { for (item in data_array)}` that walks through the data array, splitting the fields to get values to use as indices for the other two arrays and printing each line with the appropriate frequency.  Something like:

```
awk '{ data[num++] = $0;
       col1[$1]++;
       col2[$2]++
     }
   END { for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        split(data[i], field)
        printf "%s %d/%d\n", data[i], col2[field[2]], col1[field[1]]
       }
    }' < input.file
```

This only requires reading the file once, and can be extended for other columns and counts.  The `for` loop causes the data to be displayed it the same order in which it was collected.

Look at `man awk` for information on associative arrays, splitting a string, and `for`.

Comment: Thank you Greg for silution. Looks it is work. I did a update for my question. It is possible to implement your solution?

Comment: I am sure that the script I wrote can be updated to only increment the col1/col2 arrays under specific conditions, but unfortunately, I cannot figure out what those conditions from the written description.  Sorry.

Comment: In addition to having to store twice the size of the whole input file in memory courtesy of `data[$0] = $0` saving each line as both the index and the content of the array, and it would scramble the order in the output courtesy of the `in` operator. Not saying it's a bad thing, just that the OP should be aware of both situations. [@fedorqui's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41897965/1745001) has neither of those concerns.

Comment: Reasonable points. However, only 1x the data file size, plus the count arrays. The actual file data is being edited a record/line at a time. Without knowing the data size, it is hard to know whether the memory use is an issue.  Piping the output through `sort` would clean up the sort order.

Comment: @Geroge, FWIW, changed my answer so that the order of the output matches the order of the input.  I am still not sure how your description of "unique occurrences of first column" becomes the numbers you have in your example.