# Calculate statistic using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a question regarding to my previous successfully answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897791/add-frequency-number-of-occurrences-to-my-table-of-text-through-awk) by @fedorgui.

I have a table:

```
pac1 xxx 
pac1 yyy
pac1 zzz
pac2 xxx
pac2 uuu
pac3 zzz
pac3 uuu
pac4 zzz
```

And I need to calculate output like this:

```
pac1 xxx 2/4
pac1 yyy 1/4
pac1 zzz 3/4
pac2 xxx 2/4
pac2 uuu 2/4
pac3 zzz 2/4
pac3 uuu 2/4
pac4 zzz 3/4
```

Where first number is unique occurrences in column two / unique occurrences in column one (in this case xxx occurs 2 in column two and uniq column one is `4 => 2/4`

Solution works in awk is here:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {col1[$1]++; col2[$2]++; next} {print $0, col2[$2] "/" length(col1)}' file file
```

But my input could have duplicated rows like:

```
pac1 xxx
pac1 xxx 
pac1 xxx  
pac1 yyy
pac1 zzz
pac2 xxx
pac2 xxx
pac2 xxx
pac2 uuu
pac3 zzz
pac3 uuu
pac4 zzz
pac4 zzz
```

And I need to do the same computations but only for uniq rows and add this statistic to all rows like (do not compute duplications rows):

```
pac1 xxx 2/4
pac1 xxx 2/4
pac1 xxx 2/4
pac1 yyy 1/4
pac1 zzz 3/4
pac2 xxx 2/4
pac2 xxx 2/4
pac2 xxx 2/4
pac2 uuu 2/4
pac3 zzz 2/4
pac3 uuu 2/4
pac4 zzz 3/4
pac4 zzz 3/4
```

This is more complicated I have thousands of rows. Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Numbers and computation are the same like example 1 - I need to do computation like: uniq < infile | awk 'FNR==NR {col1[$1]++; col2[$2]++; next} {print $0, col2[$2] "/" length(col1)}' STDIN STDIN.. But I ned to add this information to all duplicated lines.

Comment: try `FNR==NR {if(!seen[$0]++){col1[$1]++; col2[$2]++;} next}` (but you need to remove extra spaces from end of line)... else try `if(!seen[$1$2]++)`

Comment: This I was try, but problem is, that this is part of file - I have much more columns, that are not unique, so I need to check uniq only for this two columns .

Comment: @Sundeep Better to use `seen[$1,$2]` as the fields can overlap without the `,`

Comment: @123 yeah realized it after seeing your answer... ++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check if the line is unique when adding to the second array.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];b[$2]+=!c[$1,$2]++;next}{print $0, b[$2] "/" length(a)}' test{,}

pac1 xxx 2/4
pac1 xxx  2/4
pac1 xxx   2/4
pac1 yyy 1/4
pac1 zzz 3/4
pac2 xxx 2/4
pac2 xxx 2/4
pac2 xxx 2/4
pac2 uuu 2/4
pac3 zzz 3/4
pac3 uuu 2/4
pac4 zzz 3/4
pac4 zzz 3/4
```

or if there aren't random spaces at the end of lines like your example you could just use `$0` instead of `$1,$2`

Comment: Thank you, I will test it - I can not use $0, because I have much more columns, that are not unique.