# How do I conditionally append the occurrence of a field using awk?

Tags: csv, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Level,Member
HIGH,John
HIGH,John
HIGH,Paul
HIGH,George
REG,George
REG,George
REG,George
REG,John
REG,Paul
REG,Paul
REG,Ringo
```

If I want to append a count of the occurrence of data in the second column, this works great:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{ $0=$0 OFS (++a[$2]) }1' file
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to add an if/else statement so that I can conditionally count by level so that my output looks like this:

```
Level,Member,1
HIGH,George,1
HIGH,John,1
HIGH,John,2
HIGH,Paul,1
REG,George,1
REG,George,2
REG,George,3
REG,John,1
REG,Paul,1
REG,Paul,2
REG,Ringo,1
```

Please note that the count starts over when the level changes from HIGH to REG.  The file is already sorted by level and then by member.

Comment: Very closely related: [Add frequency number of occurrences to my table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897791/add-frequency-number-of-occurrences-to-my-table-of-text-through-awk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command was already pretty fine. I have just changed the key of associative array a[]:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{ $0=$0 OFS (++a[$2$1]) }1' file
```

or:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{ $0=$0 OFS (++a[$0]) }1' file
```

Comment: Given that `a bc` and `ab c` both concatenate to `abc`, take a look at your answer and think about it the cases where it'll fail.

Answer (score 2):

or just..

```
$ awk '{$0=$0","++a[$0]}1' file
Level,Member,1
HIGH,John,1
HIGH,John,2
HIGH,Paul,1
HIGH,George,1
REG,George,1
REG,George,2
REG,George,3
REG,John,1
REG,Paul,1
REG,Paul,2
REG,Ringo,1
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
awk '{print $0","(++c[$0])}'
```

Comment: No, they're for portability. Some awks given that string-number concatenation without the parens will apply the ++ to the string before appending the number rather than incrementing the number and then prepending the string. So depending on your awk version `c=3; print "foo"++c` can output `13` rather than `foo4`. So it's safer and more portable to always write `print "foo"(++c)`.